# Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

I am trying to put a splash image `4.41 KB` in my app that I made with my Samsung S4 device but I am getting the error below when I store it in this directory `drawable-hdpi`. I have even tried to store it in  the `ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi ans xxhdpi` in this case  I am getting a white splash background without image.

I downloaded an image from the internet that has `800x600` pixel size and `494 KB`. I put it just in the `drawable-hdpi` directory and it works (The image is being dispalyed as splash) but I want to put my own S4 device image as background. How can I fix it?

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background= "@drawable/splash_background"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error:**

```
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 15857
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bustracker/com.bustracker.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at com.bustracker.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:13)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    ... 10 more
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    ... 22 more
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 153363468 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 112MB until OOM
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3970)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:507)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:191)
08-02 12:24:01.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15857):    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Try to put it on drawable res folder only.

Comment: @AawazGyawali: I am getting invalid resource directory name.

Comment: What have i to rwite at this place when I put it there? ` android:background= "@drawable/splash_background"`

Comment: I actually ment to put the image file to drawable folder. Not inside the different screen density folder.